# How to grab the first two image attachments from a post?

Tags: attachments

I am grabbing an image that is uploaded to that post working with this function: 
[wp_get_attachment_image_src](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)

```
<?php 
    $images = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'numberposts' => 2 ) );
    if ( $images ) :
            $total_images = count( $images );
            $image = array_shift( $images );
            $image_img_tag = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID, 'full' ); 
                ?>

    <div class="two_images">
        <img src="<?php echo $image_img_tag[0] ?>">
    </div>
```

How do I grab the first two images that are uploaded to a post?  I guess I need help with a foreach statement.. and limit it to two.  I tried this but it just printed the same first image over and over..

```
<?php foreach ($image as $images) { 
         echo "<img src='$image_img_tag[0]'>";
} ?>
```

IF I echo `$total_images` then I get the correct count of 2

[Here is the paste of the page](http://www.pastie.org/2171902)

Comment: do you want the first two images uploaded or the first two images in the image order as set in the gallery tab?

Comment: The image order from the gallery tab!

Comment: ! because I did not realize that was an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you may have just not had a loop setup, try this one

```
<div class="two_images">
<?php
  global $post;
  $args = array( 
    'post_parent' => $post->ID, 
    'post_type' => 'attachment', 
    'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
    'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
    'order' => 'ASC', 
    'numberposts' => 2 );
   $images = get_posts($args);
   if ( $images ) {
    $i = 0;
    while($i <= 1){
      echo wp_get_attachment_image( $images[$i]->ID, 'full' );
      $i++;
    }
  }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but that doesnt work for me

Comment: updated, should work this time